# want to remove "--Please select--" option into custom options in magento

Tags: magento

```
if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
                $select->setName('options['.$_option->getid().']');
                //    ->addOption('', $this->__('-- Please Select --')); }
```

I put this code to remove "please select" option into magento. but it is not working. i used : custom options of magento product

Comment: where you show this options like in system configuration,add new item or frontend side?

Comment: @MagikVishal : i already enter the product and i configure custom options but when i go to that particular product then i want to set default amount as an Zero but instead of that i want to be default first item to be selected. is this possible...Friend...?

Answer (score 1):

you have to overwrite below file to remove please select for cutom option

`Copy \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php to \app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php`

Find below code:

```
if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
    $select->setName('options['.$_option->getid().']')
           ->addOption('', $this->__('-- Please Select --'));
}
```

Replace it with

```
if ($_option->getType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
    $select->setName('options['.$_option->getid().']');
        // ->addOption('', $this->__('-- Please Select --'));
}
```

And you have done.